# Combine date intervals from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, date

I have daily storage room temperature measurements in a table (separate table for each room):

```
begindate | enddate  | temperature | room_id
--------------------------------------------
1/1/2014  | 1/2/2014 | 10          |  1
1/2/2014  | 1/3/2014 | 12          |  1
1/4/2014  | 1/5/2014 | 11          |  1
1/5/2014  | 1/6/2014 | 12          |  1
1/6/2014  | 1/7/2014 | 10          |  1
1/7/2014  | 1/8/2014 | 11          |  1
1/8/2014  | 1/9/2014 | 12          |  1
......
1/29/2014 | 1/30/2014| 10          |  1
1/30/2014 | 1/31/2014| 12          |  1
1/31/2014 | 2/1/2014 | 10          |  1
......
3/1/2014  | 3/2/2014 | 14          |  1
.....
Does not show all dates but the measurements are daily
```

The second table contains the dates when the storage room was occupied

```
begindate  |  enddate  | room_id
---------------------------------
1/6/2014   | 1/9/2014  |  1
1/15/2014  | 1/29/2014 |  1
3/1/2014   | 3/2/2014  |  1
```

What I need are the average room temperatures during the time when it was occupied or monthly temperatures in case the room was not occupied or occupied for the greater than a month interval.
With the above data the result should be something like:

```
begindate    |   enddate   |  avg_temp  | room_id
--------------------------------------------------
1/1/2014     |   1/6/2014  |    11      |   1
1/6/2014     |   1/9/2014  |    11      |   1
1/9/2014     |   1/15/2014 |    11      |   1
1/15/2014    |   1/29/2014 |    12      |   1
1/29/2014    |   2/1/2014  |    11      |   1
2/1/2014     |   3/1/2014  |    13      |   1
3/1/2014     |   3/2/2014  |    14      |   1
3/2/2014     |   4/1/2014  |    15      |   1
```

I tried to do it several ways but every time I get some duplicate overlapping dates or missing date intervals.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Code create temperature data table:

```
INSERT INTO @temps
values
('01/01/2014','01/02/2014','10','1'),
('01/02/2014','01/03/2014','12','1'),
('01/03/2014','01/04/2014','11','1'),
('01/04/2014','01/05/2014','11','1'),
('01/05/2014','01/06/2014','12','1'),
('01/06/2014','01/07/2014','10','1'),
('01/07/2014','01/08/2014','11','1'),
('01/08/2014','01/09/2014','12','1'),
('01/09/2014','01/10/2014','10','1'),
('01/10/2014','01/11/2014','12','1'),
('01/11/2014','01/12/2014','10','1'),
('01/12/2014','01/13/2014','10','1'),
('01/13/2014','01/14/2014','11','1'),
('01/14/2014','01/15/2014','12','1'),
('01/15/2014','01/16/2014','11','1'),
('01/16/2014','01/17/2014','14','1'),
('01/17/2014','01/18/2014','12','1'),
('01/18/2014','01/19/2014','10','1'),
('01/19/2014','01/20/2014','11','1'),
('01/20/2014','01/21/2014','10','1'),
('01/21/2014','01/22/2014','11','1'),
('01/22/2014','01/23/2014','12','1'),
('01/23/2014','01/24/2014','11','1'),
('01/24/2014','01/25/2014','14','1'),
('01/25/2014','01/26/2014','12','1'),
('01/26/2014','01/27/2014','10','1'),
('01/27/2014','01/28/2014','11','1'),
('01/28/2014','01/29/2014','10','1'),
('01/29/2014','01/30/2014','11','1'),
('01/30/2014','01/31/2014','12','1'),
('01/31/2014','02/01/2014','11','1'),
('02/01/2014','02/02/2014','14','1'),
('02/02/2014','02/03/2014','12','1'),
('02/03/2014','02/04/2014','10','1'),
('02/04/2014','02/05/2014','11','1'),
('02/05/2014','02/06/2014','10','1'),
('02/06/2014','02/07/2014','11','1'),
('02/07/2014','02/08/2014','12','1'),
('02/08/2014','02/09/2014','11','1'),
('02/09/2014','02/10/2014','14','1'),
('02/10/2014','02/11/2014','12','1'),
('02/11/2014','02/12/2014','10','1'),
('02/12/2014','02/13/2014','11','1'),
('02/13/2014','02/14/2014','10','1'),
('02/14/2014','02/15/2014','11','1'),
('02/15/2014','02/16/2014','12','1'),
('02/16/2014','02/17/2014','11','1'),
('02/17/2014','02/18/2014','14','1'),
('02/18/2014','02/19/2014','12','1'),
('02/19/2014','02/20/2014','10','1'),
('02/20/2014','02/21/2014','11','1'),
('02/21/2014','02/22/2014','10','1'),
('02/22/2014','02/23/2014','11','1'),
('02/23/2014','02/24/2014','12','1'),
('02/24/2014','02/25/2014','11','1'),
('02/25/2014','02/26/2014','14','1'),
('02/26/2014','02/27/2014','12','1'),
('02/27/2014','02/28/2014','15','1'),
('02/28/2014','03/01/2014','11','1'),
('03/01/2014','03/02/2014','11','1'),
('03/02/2014','03/03/2014','12','1'),
('03/03/2014','03/04/2014','11','1'),
('03/04/2014','03/05/2014','14','1'),
('03/05/2014','03/06/2014','12','1'),
('03/06/2014','03/07/2014','15','1'),
('03/07/2014','03/08/2014','11','1'),
('03/08/2014','03/09/2014','12','1'),
('03/09/2014','03/10/2014','11','1'),
('03/10/2014','03/11/2014','14','1'),
('03/11/2014','03/12/2014','12','1'),
('03/12/2014','03/13/2014','15','1'),
('03/13/2014','03/14/2014','11','1'),
('03/14/2014','03/15/2014','12','1'),
('03/15/2014','03/16/2014','11','1'),
('03/16/2014','03/17/2014','14','1'),
('03/17/2014','03/18/2014','12','1'),
('03/18/2014','03/19/2014','15','1'),
('03/19/2014','03/20/2014','11','1'),
('03/20/2014','03/21/2014','12','1'),
('03/21/2014','03/22/2014','11','1'),
('03/22/2014','03/23/2014','14','1'),
('03/23/2014','03/24/2014','12','1'),
('03/24/2014','03/25/2014','15','1'),
('03/25/2014','03/26/2014','11','1'),
('03/26/2014','03/27/2014','12','1'),
('03/27/2014','03/28/2014','11','1'),
('03/28/2014','03/29/2014','14','1'),
('03/29/2014','03/30/2014','12','1'),
('03/30/2014','03/31/2014','15','1'),
('03/31/2014','04/01/2014','11','1'),
('04/01/2014','04/02/2014','12','1'),
('04/02/2014','04/03/2014','11','1'),
('04/03/2014','04/04/2014','14','1'),
('04/04/2014','04/05/2014','12','1'),
('04/05/2014','04/06/2014','15','1')
```

Comment: Please post your attempt at solving this, so we can help you spot what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could something like this be what you need?

My approach is, to give the periods a key and use either the period or the year_month as key to partition the avg-function (OVER clause: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

EDIT: New approach, as the OP needs something else:

REMARK: If a "free" period must end where a real period begins and a new "free" period must follow after the real period's end I could suggest another approach, but this is to much in one answer. Please let me know...

EDIT: My "Remark" was exactly the point, so I suggest another approach:

```
SET LANGUAGE English;

DECLARE @rooms TABLE(roomID INT,room VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @rooms VALUES(1,'Room 1'),(2,'Room 2');

DECLARE @temps TABLE(begD DATE, endD DATE,temp INT, roomID INT);
INSERT INTO @temps 
VALUES('1/1/2014','1/2/2014','10','1')
     ,('1/2/2014','1/3/2014','12','1')
     ,('1/4/2014','1/5/2014','11','1')
     ,('1/5/2014','1/6/2014','12','1')
     ,('1/6/2014','1/7/2014','10','1')
     ,('1/7/2014','1/8/2014','11','1')
     ,('1/8/2014','1/9/2014','12','1')
     ,('1/29/2014','1/30/2014','10','1')
     ,('1/30/2014','1/31/2014','12','1')
     ,('1/31/2014','2/1/2014','10','1')
     ,('3/1/2014','3/2/2014','14','1');

DECLARE @periods TABLE(periodID INT, begD DATE,endD DATE,roomID INT);
INSERT INTO @periods
VALUES(1,'1/6/2014','1/9/2014','1')
     ,(2,'1/15/2014','1/29/2014','1')
     ,(3,'3/1/2014','3/2/2014','1');

DECLARE @StartDate DATE='1/1/2014';
DECLARE @DayCount INT=50;
WITH dayList AS
(
    SELECT TOP (@DayCount) DATEADD(d,numbers.nr-1,@StartDate) AS dayDate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY o.object_id) FROM sys.objects AS o
    ) AS numbers(nr)
)
,roomDayList AS
(
    SELECT dayList.dayDate,r.* 
    FROM dayList,@rooms AS r

)
,occupations AS
(
    SELECT roomDayList.dayDate
          ,roomDayList.roomID
          ,roomDayList.room
          ,ISNULL(InPeriod.PeriodID,'free') AS PeriodID
    FROM roomDayList
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT 'P'+CAST(periodID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS PeriodID
        FROM @periods AS p
        WHERE p.roomID=roomDayList.roomID
          AND roomDayList.dayDate BETWEEN p.begD AND p.endD   
    ) InPeriod
)
,periodBorders AS
(
    SELECT tbl.*
    FROM
    (
        SELECT occupations.*
              ,CASE WHEN occupations.dayDate=@StartDate THEN @StartDate ELSE CASE WHEN occupations.PeriodID<>RowBefore.PeriodID THEN occupations.dayDate ELSE NULL END END AS FirstDayOfPeriod
              ,CASE WHEN occupations.dayDate=(SELECT MAX(dayDate) FROM dayList) THEN (SELECT MAX(dayDate) FROM dayList) ELSE CASE WHEN occupations.PeriodID<>RowAfter.PeriodID THEN occupations.dayDate ELSE NULL END END AS LastDayOfPeriod
        FROM occupations
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT PeriodID
            FROM occupations AS innerOc
            WHERE innerOc.dayDate=DATEADD(d,-1,occupations.dayDate)
              AND innerOc.roomID=occupations.roomID
        ) AS RowBefore
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT PeriodID
            FROM occupations AS innerOc
            WHERE innerOc.dayDate=DATEADD(d,1,occupations.dayDate)
              AND innerOc.roomID=occupations.roomID
        ) AS RowAfter
    ) AS tbl
    WHERE tbl.FirstDayOfPeriod IS NOT NULL OR tbl.LastDayOfPeriod IS NOT NULL
)
,mergeBorders AS
(
    SELECT periodBorders.dayDate
          ,periodBorders.roomID
          ,periodBorders.room
          ,periodBorders.PeriodID
          ,periodBorders.FirstDayOfPeriod
          ,ISNULL(periodBorders.LastDayOfPeriod,PeriodEndDate.dt) AS LastDayOfPeriod
    FROM periodBorders
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 pB.LastDayOfPeriod FROM periodBorders AS pB WHERE pB.roomID=periodBorders.roomID AND pB.dayDate>periodBorders.dayDate ORDER BY pB.dayDate ASC
    ) AS PeriodEndDate(dt)
    WHERE periodBorders.FirstDayOfPeriod IS NOT NULL
)
,tempMeasures AS
(
    SELECT t.temp
          ,Period.*
    FROM @temps AS t
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM mergeBorders
        WHERE mergeBorders.roomID=t.roomID AND t.begD BETWEEN mergeBorders.FirstDayOfPeriod AND mergeBorders.LastDayOfPeriod
    ) AS Period
)
SELECT t.roomID
      ,t.FirstDayOfPeriod
      ,t.LastDayOfPeriod
      ,AVG(t.temp)
FROM tempMeasures AS t
GROUP BY t.FirstDayOfPeriod,t.LastDayOfPeriod,t.roomID
ORDER BY t.roomID,t.FirstDayOfPeriod
```

Comment: Thanks, his is something I can start working with, however I need to have only one record per periodID with begin and end date of the period.

Comment: One more suggestion: I'll edit my answer, Please look it up there (and dont forget the upvote if this is of help for you :-)   )

Comment: Well, I guess the problem starts when you do grouping : we have now the overlapping intervals. For example, there is date interval 1/1/2014 to 1/31/2014 that covers 2 other intervals - 1/6/2014 to 1/9/2014 and 1/15/2014 to 1/29/2014.
Instead of these 3 intervals we should have 1/1/2014 to 1/6/2014, 1/6/2014 to 1/9/2014, 1/9/2014 to 1/15/2014, 1/15/2014 to 1/29/2014, and 1/29/2014 to 2/1/2014.

Comment: It was quite a challenge and I couldn't stop :-)  My solution is edited within the answer. Hope this is what you need... If yes, please mark the answer, thx!

Comment: Sorry, took quite a while to verify that the whole thing works. But it does. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear this! I like such puzzling, but I must be aware of time and power :-)   One more thing: Please have in mind, that this might not work properly with a period or a gap of just one single day...